# Google sheets sum of vlookups

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I have some data in Google Sheets that looks a bit like the following:

[table of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm8YN.png)

I need a formula that filters for each unique value in column A, returns the value in column C and then sums those values (basically like a sum of vlookups).

The answer should be 6000, so far the closest I'm getting is 9000 from this formula: =sumif(A4:C12, unique(A4:A12), C4:C12)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're saying the value of column C is dependent on the value of column A. In the example you gave, red is always 3000, blue is always 2000, and green is always 1000.

If that's the case, `=SUM(UNIQUE(C4:C12))` would give you they answer you're looking for.

If that's not the case, I don't think you can do what you're asking. If the Red values were, for example, 3001, 3002, and 3003, how would you know which one to sum?

Comment: Thanks @veryrad I managed to solve this one by using:

=sum(unique(query($A$15:$J, "select A,F")))

so that only the unique rows are computed